# How to measure time from send and receive in scapy?

Tags: ip, scapy, icmp

I write such code in scapy to make simple ping - nothing special but it looks promising.

```
def ping(ip):
    answer = sr1(IP(dst=ip) / ICMP())
```

How can I measure travel time from send to receive in scapy. Question is very simple but also very essential to learn it. I searching some solution in internet and documentation but without effect.

Can you help with it?

Full code look like this but measure ping is too long.

```
import time

from scapy.layers.inet import ICMP, IP
from scapy.sendrecv import sr1, sr


def ping(ip):
    packet = IP(dst=ip) / ICMP()
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    answer = sr1(packet)
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    print(t1 - t0)

    answer.show()
    answer[ICMP].show()

ping('192.168.1.1')
```

Result of `t1 - t0 = 0.12669169999999985s`.
`ping.exe = 4ms` so something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `sent_time` parameter. For instance, if you are using `sr`, you can do:

```
ans, unans = sr(IP(dst="www.google.com")/ICMP())
timestamp = ans[0][1].time - ans[0][0].sent_time
```

In your example:

```
packet = IP(dst=ip)/ICMP()
a = sr1(packet)
timestamp = a.time - packet.sent_time
```

Works too

Comment: It works only problem is that scapy measurement is invalid :) Ping is 50ms but scapy measure 98ms (sometimes 50ms - maybe my connection is wrong I need to check). I found also ping3 library so I can replace code if need.

Comment: You might want to retry using current dev version. It has been a bit glitchy

Comment: Maybe dev version has better time calculation I will test it after it will be stable. I will use scapy for traceroute and dns queries - ping3 can be good for ping only after some changes (have some bug with long length ping). I want to measure quality of internet route continuously to check quality problems location.

Comment: @Chameleon  I use Scapy 2.5.0，The ping command and the scapy measurement value are equal.

Comment: I confirm @tinyhare comment. I had similar problem with version 2.4.3 on windows but after updating to 2.5 this problem seems to be solved (profiling both versions shows that the previous version used time.sleep which suggests a polling based implementation, but it is completely changed in this version)