# How can I measure latency with scapy?

Tags: python, scapy, latency

This is related to

[How to measure time from send and receive in scapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432123/how-to-measure-time-from-send-and-receive-in-scapy)

However I can't use ICMP because host doesn't respond to it. I tried to adjust above answer:

```
packet = IP(dst="www.google.com")/TCP(dport=80,flags="S")
a = sr1(packet)
timestamp = a.time - packet.sent_time
```

But `timestamp` is always a negative number. Idea is to get latency in ms as output.